# What is the minimum voltage for general loads and peltier units

Tags: power, maximum-ratings, ratings

I am confused with "power ratings" on devices and electrical components.

1. First, what is the power rating on a home appliance or a electrical component saying when it is 12V? Is it saying "we would prefer a 12V power source"? OR "we need at least a 12V power source?" or "we can't take more than 12V power source"? Or does the answer depend on the device/component? (ie some are minimum, some are recommended, some are required)
2. Home appliance says it is 12V. But we plug it into a wall power point which is 230V power source (in New Zealand). How are these two compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The voltage (not power) rating on an appliance or electronic device is the voltage that the device is designed to operate on.  If you have a 12 volt car radio, and connect it to a 6 volt battery, the radio is very unlikely to operate, but will not be damaged.  If instead you connect it to a 24 volt battery, the radio will very likely be destroyed because it is not designed to handle that voltage.

If you connect a device rated for 12 volts to your 230 volt mains, you will likely get smoke, flames, much excitement, and a destroyed device.

Many electronic devices these days are rated for 12 volts or other low voltage, but come with a power supply that can plug into 230 volt mains, and reduce the voltage to the required voltage.  Many such power supplies are built into the mains plug (we often call them "wall warts"), so to many people, they may just appear to be a mains plug.  If you look at the lable on one of these "wall warts", you should see input and output voltages listed.

Comment: Your answers are like a putting a plus sign on a mosquito bite. Very satisfactory. Many thanks.